# Method execution retry

Tags: java, loops

I would like to try to re-run my application if an error occures in startup procedure.

This is my approach:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(StatisticsApplication.class, args);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        SpringApplication.run(StatisticsApplication.class, args);
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not execute getConnection().", e);
    }
}
```

Sadly, it's not working correctly. If the app start fails, it restarts again once and then quits.

Comment: remove the throw new RuntimeException statement. Better yet, remove everything in the catch block. but this 'll just land you with an infinite loop. Better to implement a limit

Comment: I'm curious about what you expect to change between attempts at starting your application - if the code and config remain the same between each iteration of your loop, why would the outcome be any different?

Comment: From this code snippet it is visible that you are trying to get a connection to an external resource or server during startup and the same may fail.

Can you please edit your question and paste the code of the application where you are trying to get the connection ?

Answer (score 4):

**I strongly recommend to not use your current approach which is very risky.**

I suggest you to use **`Spring Retry`** instead : [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry)

> This project provides declarative retry support for Spring
>   applications. It is used in Spring Batch, Spring Integration, Spring
>   for Apache Hadoop (amongst others).
>
> ### Quick Start
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableRetry
> public class Application {
>
>     @Bean
>     public Service service() {
>         return new Service();
>     }
>
> }
>
> @Service
> class Service {
>     @Retryable(RemoteAccessException.class)
>     public void service() {
>         // ... do something
>     }
>     @Recover
>     public void recover(RemoteAccessException e) {
>        // ... panic
>     }
> }
> ```

Here's another guide about how to use Spring Retry :

- [Guide to Spring Retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helps. It's a very usefull solution for batch and integration context.